# Contacts not showing for first time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, abaddressbook

When I try to load the table view with the list of contacts, it is not showing for the first time. But if I try Pull-To-Refresh or go to some view and come back to table view controller, the contacts are loading and showing perfectly. Here is the code:

```
func getContactNames()
{    
    let allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as Array
    for record in allContacts {
        let currentContact: ABRecordRef = record
        let currentContactName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(currentContact)?.takeRetainedValue()
            as? String

        if(currentContactName != nil) {
            self.arrFriendsList.append(currentContactName! as String)
        }
    }

    // For alphabatically arranging
    self.arrFriendsList = self.arrFriendsList.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }

    self.arrFilteredTableData = self.arrFriendsList
    self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```

I am calling this function in viewDidLoad method. Any idea for solution? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Instead call the method in viewDidAppear()

Comment: set delegate and datasource explicitly         self.yourTableView.delegate = self;
        self.yourTableView.dataSource = self;  in view did load

Comment: tried, same issue :(

Comment: My bad, could you share the delegate and datasource methods.which would help me understand more.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. am just using this function to load the contacts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87992/discussion-between-prabhu-somasundaram-and-aaa).